# Refreshing WinDir whilst using MicroPython

Tags: python, python-3.x, micropython

I'm new to both Python and MicroPython, but i'm getting the hang of this interesting approach at embedded programming!

After creating a new file with the PyBoard, I was wondering whether there is a clever way to *refresh* the
[Windows Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGf6Z.png) of the representation of the PyBoard flashDir, and then seeing the change in the windows directory. 
Currently, i have to turn off and reload the PyBoard to see the change in a windows directory.
I am aware that i am able to see the file using os.listdir() in a REPL.

Comment: So refreshing the Windows Explorer window, with its refresh button or right-click menu, doesn't work? Or are you asking for something that can be triggered by code on the Pyboard?

Comment: @nekomatic exactly - it's as if the file actually doesn't exists in the flash (according to windows) until i power off and on the PyBoard.

Comment: Having dug about a bit in the [documentation](http://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/) and [forum](https://forum.micropython.org/) I think this is expected behaviour: the desktop OS assumes it has sole access to a drive mounted by USB and does not expect its contents to change except by the OS writing to it. I suggest you ask on the forum to find the best workaround for what you want to do.

Comment: @nekomatic, cool of you - thanks! I might try and do that.